# Best way to connect a Microchip card to Android Tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb, microchip, wifi-direct

I used [Anothem](http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/)'s guide to USB-connect an android tablet to Windows with ADB. Now I need to move forward to the next step and connect a microchip card to the tablet.

I got these 2 cards for USB testing purposes:
[1. Microcip FS USB](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en021940)
[2. Microcip PIC24F Accessory Development Starter Kit for Android](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en553673)

I can connect them to the computer and test leds, switches etc., however when it comes to android tablet things don't go smooth. When I connect card number 2, tablet notices that some USB is plugged in but the software provided by Microchip don't recognize the drive so it fails. When I connect number 1 (FS USB), nothing happens. It should be related to power, even though I'm using an external power source for FS USB.

Anyway, my question is: what is the "best (safest)" way to connect an electronic card to an Android Tablet. As far as I know, there are 3 options:
**1. USB:** There are library and compatibility issues
**2. Bluetooth:** Need external Bluetooth adapters for both card and tablet
**3. WiFi (Direct):** Probably need to buy an expensive tablet with WiFi direct also a WiFi adapter on card

Can you tell me the safest way to connect a card to a tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB:
+ Can test via emulator
+ Cable is always safer than wireless
+ Faster
- Need to stay within USB-cable range
- Library and compatibility issues

Bluetooth:
+ No wires
- Battery consumption
- Slow
- Had so many problems with android activity - service - client connections

So I'm gonna go with USB (for now)